# "Cannot set terminal process group" during su to another user as login shell

Tags: debian, bash, debian-squeeze, terminal, su

*Note: Please read the updated information starting with "EDIT" near the halfway point of this post - the environment and background of this problem has changed*

I've got a bog standard Debian 6.0 install here that I decided to sidegrade to the Debian Testing repositories. I did this by swapping out the references to the Squeeze repos in my sources.list to use the Testing repos instead.

After the package install and a reboot, I get the following error when attempting to su - to another user:

```
root@skaia:~# su joebloggs -
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

If I omit the -, this does not occur.

Note that users can become root correctly, this only seems to happen when switching from root to somebody else and using the - to get that user's environment.

Google is mostly useless here. The only things I can find are references from 2011 in regards to the `sux` package, which appear to have been fixed in the mean time.

This looks and smells very much like an upgrade error, fixable by tweaking the right package in the right manner. I just have no idea where to start - aside from this, my system works completely normally and as expected.

*EDIT*

This is now happening to me on a Debian **stable** machine as described above. No upgrade or anything this time, just straight up stable.

Yup, a year later. Still no idea what the heck the problem is.

Here's what it looks like now (not much has changed):

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
terraria@skaianet:~$ tty
/dev/pts/0
terraria@skaianet:~$ ls -l /dev/pts/0
crw--w---- 1 root root 136, 0 Oct 10 19:21 /dev/pts/0
terraria@skaianet:~$ ls -l /dev/pts/
crw--w---- 1 root root 136, 0 Oct 10 19:21 0
crw--w---- 1 root root 136, 2 Sep 22 17:47 2
crw--w---- 1 root root 136, 3 Sep 26 19:30 3
c--------- 1 root root   5, 2 Sep  7 10:50 ptmx
```

An strace generated like this:

```
root@skaianet:~$ strace -f -o tracelog su terraria -
```

..also turns up some confusing behavior. These messages are rather confusing. Some chosen lines:

```
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/0", 4095) = 10
#Error code 10? 
15503 open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
#Yes there is, and I can interact with it normally
15503 ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [32561])    = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

I've linked [the full output of this strace session](http://pastebin.com/Q7k7tsME) - all I did was run the su command, then immediately ctrl+d out of the terminal.

Comment: Hi Mike. Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- `su - username` is interpreted by your `su` to mean "run *username*'s shell as an interactive login shell"
- `su username -` is interpreted by your `su` to mean "run the following **non-interactive** command (`-`) as *username*"
- the latter only worked at all because:

  - your `su` passes trailing arguments to `sh` for parsing
  - `sh` takes `-` to mean "run as a login shell (read `/etc/profile`, ...)"

But what you're really interested in is: why *non-interactive*?  Sharing the controlling terminal between the privileged parent and the unprivileged child leaves you vulnerable to "[TTY pushback privilege escalation](http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/)", aka the `TIOCSTI` bug, so unless you really need it `su` [detaches from it](http://sources.debian.net/src/shadow/1:4.2-2/src/su.c#L1093).  When you used the `su username -` form, `su` [inferred that you didn't need a controlling terminal](http://sources.debian.net/src/shadow/1:4.2-2/src/su.c#L788]).

Only processes with a controlling terminal can have session leaders which manipulate process groups (do job control); the trace you gave is `bash` detecting that it can't be a session leader.

You mention:

> Where it gets stranger is that both forms work fine on Ubuntu and CentOS 6, however on vanilla Debian, only the first form works without error.

Ignoring variants like `sux` and `sudo`, there are at least three<sup>[1]</sup> versions of `su` on Linux: `coreutils`, `util-linux` and `shadow-utils` from which Debian's comes.  The latter's manpage points out:

> This version of su has many compilation options, only some of which may be in use at any particular site.

and Debian's comes with the flag `old_debian_behavior`; other versions may have similar compile-time/runtime options.  Another reason for variability might be that there was some [debate](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/06/08/3)<sup>[2]</sup> as to whether `su` should ever be used to drop privilege this way and whether the  `TIOCSTI` bug is therefore a bug at all (Redhat originally [closed it "WONTFIX"](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2005-4890)).

[1]: Edit: add `SimplePAMApps` and `hardened-shadow` to that.

[2]: Solar Designer has [some (old) opinions there](http://www.openwall.com/lists/owl-users/2004/10/20/6) which I think are worth a read.

Comment: That is an excellent answer and best of all it exactly explains why. I wish you'd been here a year ago :)

Answer (score 1):

I would check the ownership and permissions on /dev/pts* or for a new configuration for udev related to /dev/pts devices, that was not replaced during the upgrade process.

You can also try to find out what syscal is generating the error by running as root:

```
strace -f su - username 2>stderr.log
```

Comment: Better add `-f` to that strace, in case su decides to run the shell as a subprocess, which seems to be common now. The syscall for setting a terminal's foreground process group is `ioctl(..., TIOCSPGRP, ...)` and we already know it failed with ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) so that part of the strace won't help much. But an strace of both versions of the command (with and without `-`) could be compared to find out *why* the TIOCSPGRP fails.

Comment: That looks like a promising lead. Looking in my /dev/pts folder, there are precisely two items, namely 0, permissions set as 600 owned by the user I logged in as, and a `ptmx` owned by root, with zero permissions.

Comment: When you get the shell prompt after the `No job control` message, run the command `tty` and it will tell you which tty you're on. Then `ls -l` it.

Comment: @AlanCurry, you are right, I will add `-f`. Thank you!

Comment: @AlanCurry - it came back. I've updated the original question with the information Mircea suggested.

Comment: I think it is a bug in `su`. See this bug report: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663200

Comment: Try the same command with `sudo` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Additional explanation, I encountered the same problem, but different solutions.
Use `su -l $USER -P` to provide a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: This has solved my problem. It avoids TIOCSTI ioctl terminal injection which was causing the issue.